# Replacement for the site "Dll Help"

Tags: dll, resources

I just found out about the site [DllHelp](http://support.microsoft.com/dllhelp/), and it turns out it was retired yesterday! :-(

The site is: (according to [Joel on software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/news/20030102.html))

> a complete database of every DLL Microsoft has ever shipped, and which versions of which product it shipped with.

Is anyone aware of a replacement / equivalent site, or is this information simply no longer available / relevant?

Comment: This isn't really a Stackoverflow-appropriate question- Superuser maybe?

Comment: @Nathan - From what I can tell the site was intended as a developer resource rather than a user resource, hence posting on StackOverflow - however if you think I'm likey to get a better response on SuperUser then I wont feel offended if you vote to close :-)

Comment: I suppose you could wait for a while for the page to be archived... http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://support.microsoft.com/dllhelp/